# Caratheodory's theorem in any compact Riemann surface

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, geometric-measure-theory

The classical Caratheodory theorem states that if $G$ is a simply connected domain in the plane, whose boundary is a Jordan curve, then the Riemann uniformization extends continuously to a homeomorphism between the boundary of $G$ and the unit circle.

Question: does this hold if the domain is embedded in a compact Riemann surface of higher genus? More precisely, is it true that if $G$ is a simply connected domain in a compact Riemann surface $X$, and if the boundary of $G$ is a simple closed curve, then the uniformizing map extends as a homeomorphism between the boundary of $G$ and the unit circle?

Comment: The uniformization theorem applied to $X$ gives that its universal cover is one of $\Bbb P^1, \Bbb C, $ or the unit disc. The compact simply connected domain $G$ lifts to the universal cover, which exhibits it as a subset of $\Bbb C$. So this is just the classical Caratheodary theorem.

Comment: @MikeMiller I thought of that, but a priori lifting to the universal cover will change the boundary. Is there a simple argument why the closure of $G$ would lift to the closure of a Jordan domain?

Comment: I said "compact domain" for a reason --- you should include the boundary of $G$ when talking about lifting it, so that $G$ is homeomorphic to a closed unit disc. Then the whole closed unit disc lifts to the universal cover, giving a closed unit disc embedded upstairs (the boundary lifting the boundary, the interior lifting the interior).

Comment: @MikeMiller I see, but if I may ask one more stupid question: how do you know that the closure of $G$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit disk? this seems sort of close to proving what we want (keeping in mind that in general the closure of a simply connected domain needs not be simply connected, of course)

Comment: This seems trickier than I thought at first, but still not too bad. A proof uses that any embedded curve $C \subset S$ in a surface has, for any point $p \in C$, a neighborhood $U$ and a homeomorphism $f: U \to \Bbb R^2$ with $f(C \cap U) = \Bbb R$ and $f(p) = 0$. Then $f(G \cap U)$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^2$ with boundary $\Bbb R$. Some fiddling shows that it must either be one open half-plane or the union of both; a little more shows that whether it's one half-plane or two is independent of the point $p \in C$. But if it was both, then we would have $G = S \setminus C$, which is not s.c.

Comment: So $\overline G$ is a manifold with interior an open disc, and so it is homeomorphic to the closed unit disc.